# Nuget - "Name cannot begin with the '<' character

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have VS 2013 update 5. I right click a project and select "Manage NuGet Packages". When I try to install the "SpecFlow" package I get the message:

> "Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C,
>   Line 10, position 2."

[image]

I get the same problem if I use the package manager console

[image]

Any ideas which file it's referring to? How can I fix this?

Comment: Try installing it via Nuget console: `nuget install SpecFlow`

Comment: Do you mean from the package manager console? I get "the term 'nuget' is not recognized"

Comment: try running `Install-Package SpecFlow` ?

Comment: ah ok - then I get the same error: "Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C, Line 10, position 2."

Comment: Are you using the latest NuGet version? you can download the VS 2013 extension from https://www.nuget.org/downloads

Comment: Yes, I have the latest version of "Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio" v 2.12.0.817

Comment: did you try the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997963 ?

Comment: Yes, I tried "nuking the entire package folder and restoring straight from NuGet" but no change 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any ideas which file it's referring to? How can I fix this?

Could you build your application successfully before install the package `SpecFlow`? It is seems like **there could be an error in `web.config` or some other file that has an unexpected end tag**.

According to your build log in the output:

[image]

You can notice that that package already installed to the project successfully, but NuGet would throw an exception when adding package to Common.Components. You can try install this package to the new create project and check if you still see the issue.

As a test, I created a new ASP.NET Web API project and delete a `>` tag in the web.config. Then I tried to install NuGet package to the project with  this malformed web.config I get the following error:

[image]

So my suggestion is to double check all the files that has any relations to project (like some properties bound to the settings, resources you've set in the designer previously, project reference)

Note: Many malformed errors able to build without mentioning any warnings. So we also need to check malformed error manually.

Comment: Many thanks Leo. On your advice I found that the App.config file on the Common.Components project contained a row of <<< chars - presumably as the result of some failed Git merge.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error when starting my ASP.NET server locally. The error message stated that the XML was malformed in `web.config` at a particular line, and I drove myself insane looking for the error in that file.

If you've got an error like this, look for nodes in `web.config` that import another file, like `<appSettings file="PrivateSettings.config">`.

This statement will actually inject the contents of that file at that line, and the error message will not contain the actual XML being parsed.

Check the contents of the other files that may be injected during parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my answer since I had this same issue but the solution was different for me. Rob Bowman's comment was a hint for me. I was working on a local branch and wanted to switch back to the master branch to take a look at something. When switching branches I opted to stash my changes. Visual Studio screwed up something in the process. I opened up the web.config file and found some odd code in there about a stash. I went back and committed my changes in the first branch and addressed any **issues with branch changes/stashes** then this error went away without having to do any manual code editing.